# How to map ExpandoObject (or dynamic) onto instance?

Tags: automapper

I am having issue with mapping dynamic or ExpandoObject onto instance of the destination type. I know documentation says that no mapping needs to be created upfront to map dynamic type, but what if I want to do some post processing. For example I have this

```
  this.CreateMap<ExpandoObject,CustomerCreatedEvent>()
        .AfterMap(( o,  @event) => @event.NewProp = "some default value" );
```

And when I try to map

```
  dynamic evnt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));

  var instanceType = Type.GetType((string) eventClrTypeName);

  var eventInstance = _mapper.Map(evnt, evnt.GetType(), instanceType);
```

I get only "NewProp" mapped, and all other properties are set to default value, no assignment happens.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/88a7c788124c184ca570d21f4dda4da32cb17a3b/src/UnitTests/Bug/AfterMapNestedObjects.cs#L39

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yes, that won't work. I'm suggesting smth that should work.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).